# Retry Connection after Socket Timeout (Rust)

Tags: sockets, rust, tcp

Is it possible to make a TCP Socket retry the connection after it has failed connecting? Im trying to create a basic client and server program in rust (im new) and im trying to make the client reconnect after it has failed connecting until the server starts back up.

Comment: Close the socket and make a new one, probably

Comment: As @user253751 said, just put it into a loop, and once returned, reconnect

Answer (score -2):

```
fn connect(ipport:&str) -> io::Result<net::TcpStream>{
loop{
let stream = net::TcpStream::connect(ipport);
match stream {
  Ok(stream) => return Ok(stream),
  Err(_) => continue,
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your answer to include a description of what your code does.